# change_forward_address method Disappeared

Tags: smart-contract

I follow this instruction [link](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/tree/main/upgradeable-contracts/forward-calls)  to deploy an upgradable contract link. When I have to deploy the contract only gives me 2 methods flip and get. When I want to change the forward contract to invoke the change_forward_address method, the method Disappeared. Please help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned at the end of the [README](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/tree/main/upgradeable-contracts/forward-calls) :

> *To change the address of the smart contract where calls are forwarded
> to, you would switch the metadata (i.e. the Contract ABI) back to the
> forwards_calls contract and then invoke the change_forward_address
> message.*

You would have to change again the metadata of the contract "FLIPPER PROXY" (assuming that this is the "FORWARD CALLS" contract that you initially changed its metadata) following the same steps (also mentioned in the README) as before in polkadot-js apps:

- Click on the name of `FLIPPER_PROXY` and copy its address
- Click on the top right button "Add an existing contract", insert the just copied address and upload the `forward_calls.contract` for the Contract ABI.

Then the methods `changeForwardAddress` and `forward` should re-appear under "FLIPPER PROXY".

Comment: Thanks for replay, It Solved